# Calling convention change for constructors with ellipsis

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am working with a library which has a class which takes a variable number of arguments in its constructor. When I change this class so that it inherits from a virtual base like so:

```
class A:public virtual B {
public:
   A(int i, ...);
}
```

The compiler gives the following warning:

> 'function' : constructor for class with virtual bases has '...'; calls may not be compatible with older versions of Visual C++

Ms docs has this to say on the subject of warning C4256:

> Possible incompatibility.
> Consider the following code example. If the definition of the constructor S2::S2( int i, ... ) was compiled by using a version of the Microsoft C++ compiler before version 7, but the following example is compiled by using the current version, the call to the constructor for S3 would not work correctly because of a special-case calling-convention change. If both were compiled by using Visual C++ 6.0, the call would not work quite right either, unless no parameters were passed for the ellipsis.

Can anyone tell me what the 'special-case calling-convention change' is? From what I understand, all variable argument functions have always been implemented as cdecl?

Comment: Do you need to worry about compatibility with 15 year old compilers? Visual c++ 8 was released in 2005

Comment: @AlanBirtles, no I don't. I am asking out of curiosity.